# Why my Boto3 start_task() fails with this exception: instanceId length should be one of [32,36]?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

Working on starting a new ECS task using Boto3. Here is the snippet:

```
responseStartTask = client.start_task(
cluster=clstr,
containerInstances=[
    "e21200f598xxxx26bd32xxxxxfccxxxx-2355xxxx0",
],
taskDefinition=taskDefinition,
networkConfiguration={
    'awsvpcConfiguration': {
        'subnets': [
            'subnet-06b1exxxxx8eb5312',
            'subnet-0ccf0b4xxxxx8df77',
            'subnet-0334eaxxxxx441f63'
        ],
        'securityGroups': [
            'sg-053356faxxxxxx400',
        ]
    }
})
```

But this fails with this exception:

**An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the StartTask operation: instanceId length should be one of [32,36]**

Could you please help me out in what to pass in for this *containerInstances* parameter ? (Currently I have passed container runtime ID from the ECS task details)

Comment: You might want to use the [run_task API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.run_task), it doesn't require that configuration and achieves the same thing.

Comment: Tried just now and it gives this error:   No Container Instances were found in your cluster

Comment: Well, if there are no instances in the cluster that can host the container you can't start one. Either provision instances in the cluster or create a fargate based cluster and use instances managed by AWS.

Comment: Yes have used fargate based cluster and not sure how to specify the instance IDs while starting a new ECS task. Pleas help me out

Comment: e21200f598xxxx26bd32xxxxxfccxxxx-2355xxxx0 is incorrect instance id.

Comment: You don't specify instance ID with Fargate. You appear to be missing the `launchType` attribute, so ECS doesn't know you want it to use Fargate for this task.

Comment: yes, that resolved. Thanks Mark